# Difference adapter and decorator

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm lerning design patterns and now I'm trying to understand the difference between adapter and decorator. Consider the following decorator on the List:

```
Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> lst)
```

creates a synchronized decorator on the specified `List`. The adapter pattern, in turn, also incapsulates it as said [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Example:

```
public interface Chief {

    public Object makeBreakfast();
    public Object makeDinner();
    public Object makeSupper();

}

public class Plumber {

    public Object getPipe(){
        return new Object();
    }

    public Object getKey(){
        return new Object();
    }

    public Object getScrewDriver(){
        return new Object();
    }

}

public class ChiefAdapter implements Chief{

    private Plumber plumber = new Plumber();

    @Override
    public Object makeBreakfast() {
        return plumber.getKey();
    }

    @Override
    public Object makeDinner() {
        return plumber.getScrewDriver();
    }

    @Override
    public Object makeSupper() {
        return plumber.getPipe();
    }

}
```

Couldn't someone explain the difference?

Comment: There's another kind of Adapter called "Class Form of Adapter" so that `ChiefAdapter implements Chief extends Plumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decorator pattern is primarily for the purpose taking/introducing additional responsibility to a class. For example you can take a class container of sequence of objects and implement a iterator to give additional responsibility of, ability iterate that collection inside the class.

Gof

> attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically.
>   Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending
>   functionality.

On the other side, Adapter is convert a class to another responsibility, as in the example you have shown, adapter converts the plumber to be a chef.

Gof

> convert the interface of a class into another interface clients
>   expect. Adapater lets classes work together that couldn't otherwise
>   because of incompatible interfaces.

Comment: Through the adpter pattern we can tie objects that are not inteded to work with each other, right?

Comment: correct. you convert a class into another form which otherwise would be incompatible to operate with an interface

Answer (score 1):

A decorator 'decorates' the an existing interface with additional functionality but the interface and type of the new instance remains the same - note how synchronizedList takes a List and returns a List. Adapter 'adapts' a particular interface to appear as a completely different, unrelated interface - in your case, it turns a Plumber into a Chief, an entirely different type.

Answer (score 0):

Decorator : you want to add functionality to a class but you do not want to use inheritance (use a instance of the base class), see (open closed principle)

Adapter: you have a class that you want to user but those method are different to the one use in you program, you create a class that contain an instance o this class and you program does has to talk to this class directly, see (liskov substitution principle).